# singleton template as base class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, derived

According to [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289)  I wrote a singleton template

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    public:
        static T& getInstance()
        {
            static T instance;
            return instance;
        }
    protected:
        Singleton() {}
        ~Singleton() {}
    public:
        Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
        Singleton& operator=(Singleton const &) = delete;
};
```

And then I wrote a Logger singleton(The first one)

```
class Logger                            // not derived Singleton<Logger>
{
    friend class Singleton<Logger>;
    private:
        Logger(){};
        ~Logger(){};                          
    public:
        void print(void){std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
};

int main(void)
{
    Singleton<Logger>::getInstance().print(); // use Singleton<Logger>
    return 0;
}
```

but I can also(The second one)

```
class Logger:public Singleton<Logger>    // derived Singleton<Logger>
{
    friend class Singleton<Logger>;
    private:
        Logger(){};
        ~Logger(){};                          
    public:
        void print(void){std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
};

int main(void)
{
    Logger::getInstance().print();      // use Logger
    return 0;
}
```

Then my questions are

1. Is my singleton template correct?
2. If singleton template is correct, the both Logger is correct?
3. The difference between the first one and the second one,which one is better?

**UPDATE**
After the answers,I learned that the first one allows to have several logger and the `singleton` class seems unneeded.SO I *discard* the first one.
About the seconde one I *omit* the destructor and then complier would generate a default inline public one. That seems more concise and more efficient.

```
class Logger:public Singleton<Logger>    // derived Singleton<Logger>
{
    friend class Singleton<Logger>;
    private:
        Logger(){};                       
    public:
        void print(void){std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
};
```

Comment: Might want to read http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html - don't use singletons if you can avoid it!

Comment: @Danh Just the typing?

Comment: @saeidzamani  It's necessary.  It would access the `Logger(){}` and `Logger(){}`is private

Comment: @JCRunner You are right. i delete my comment.

Comment: How is it that nobody voted _which one is better_ as primarily opinion-based? Also, define _correct_. From the point of view of the language or the software design (that sounds as well primary opinion-based a question)?

Comment: @skypjack I also hope someone can answer *From the point of view of the language or the software design*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is my singleton template correct?

Yes it is.

> 2. If singleton template is correct, the both Logger is correct?

Your first snippet allows to have several logger thanks to copy constructor.
So in this regard, it is incorrect.

> 3. The difference between the first one and the second one, which one is better?

If you fix first snippet to disallow also copy constructor, then you miss only the basic `getInstance` and your `Singleton` class seems unneeded.

With second snippet, you may even omit the destructor.

Comment: @CinCout: `Logger` constructor/destructor are private. and `getInstance` use both. it can thank to friendship.

Answer (score 1):

1)Your singleton template is correct.

2)Your both logger is correct. but the second one is a bad practice. because it's not necessary that logger derived from singleton template.
you can examine this by put this line in second one :

```
Singleton<Logger>::getInstance().print();
```

works fine.

3)the first one is better.

Comment: How derived from the template can be bad practice if the template is correct ? (look at **`protected`** section).

Comment: @Jarod42 Derived from the template class is not bad practice. adding unnecessary complexity is a bad  practice.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm sorry that I just can not get your meaning.Is your meaning is make `Singleton() {}` and `~Singleton() {}` private and use the first one?

Comment: @JCRunner I think also it's better that make them private.

Comment: @saeidzamani cool! I just do this.

Comment: @saeidzamani I used the second one.As Jarod42's said, after disallowing the copy constructor and adding basic `getInstance`,the `singleton`class seems unneeded.